# How to select all *renderable* text elements in browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, cross-browser

How can I select all visible renderable HTML text nodes in a browser document?

In other words, how can I get a list of DOM nodes I can traverse via scripting in order to obtain the text that is actually visible to the user in the browser, in document order?

I would like to rely on the browser to tell me the nodes that constitute currently visible renderable text. I'm not sure where to start. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky, but here's what I've come up with:

```
function traverse(o) {
  var a = [];
  [].forEach.call(o.childNodes, function(val) {
    if(val.nodeType===3) {
      if(val.nodeValue.trim()>'') a.push(val);
    }
    else {
      var style= getComputedStyle(val);
      if(val.tagName!=='NOSCRIPT' && 
         style.getPropertyValue('display')!=='none' &&
         style.getPropertyValue('visibility')!=='hidden' &&
         style.getPropertyValue('opacity')!=='0' &&
         style.getPropertyValue('color')!==style.getPropertyValue('background-color')
        ) {
        a= a.concat(traverse(val));
      }
    }
  });
  return a;
} //traverse

var textNodes= traverse(document.body);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/se4ep7ye/)

This does *not* check if text nodes are hidden behind other elements or if they are absolutely positioned offscreen.

Comment: how does this detect and remove hidden content?

Comment: @dandavis, now updated, but I may be overlooking something else.

Comment: Ran it in Chrome console on this very page, and it seems generally to work, but I note that the 0th element of the `textNodes` array has text `'<div id="noscript-padding">'`, which comes from a `<noscript><div id="noscript-padding"></div></noscript>` element. That probably shouldn't be there...

Comment: Ha, always something.  Now updated, plus I added an additional test to see if the font color was the same as its background color.

Comment: Nice recursive solution. This is how I would have done it if I had read the question properly, although I would have been tempted to just use jQuery to determine the [visibility](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: Thanks.  jQuery would have certainly simplified things, but it wasn't tagged.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `getComputedStyle()` is only supported in IE9+

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in 1 line of JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("body").innerText
```

Comment: wouldn't that grab hidden content as well?

Comment: @dandavis [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText): "innerText is aware of style and will not return the text of hidden elements"

Comment: @dave: Do you happen to know if it works that way (not return any text from hidden elements) in all browsers? MDN only notes basic support for all mayor (desktop) browsers, but doesn’t say if it is implemented this exact same way in all. Also, the specification linked on the MDN page says nothing about hidden elements as far as I can see.

Comment: Upvote for the MDN quote.  However, I think OP wants a list of text nodes rather than the full `innerText`.

Comment: @dave, doesn't this grab the text as a big string? I hope it was clear in my question that **I don't want a string of text**. I want the string of *nodes* that, when processed in order, comprise the string of text.

Comment: @CBroe the exact quote I gave was copied directly from that page, so you must have missed it. I can't say for sure what mobile browsers support this property, but in my experience Safari, Chrome, FireFox, and IE browsers have nearly identical support across mobile/desktop, and native android browser closely follows Chrome. I'm not generally interested in any other mobile browsers unless it's for a specific client requirement.

Comment: I misread the question, sorry. I thought you just wanted the text. I'm going to leave the answer though because I think it's a good solution if just the text is what you want.

Comment: @dave: I know you quoted it, but to me this doesn’t seem to necessarily mean that all browsers support it in that way; especially since the spec doesn’t seem to mention that particular behavior either. Was just wondering if you have any definitive info on browser supports, that’s all.

Comment: well, innerText doesn't work at all in firefox, so i personally wouldn't want to count on it.

Comment: @CBroe well I can [confirm](http://jsfiddle.net/41wvfwd3/) that it works in IE, Chrome, iPhone Safari, Android Chrome, and Android Browser, but not FireFox. I suppose it's not all that useful without FireFox support.